# Getting field values of Json Object from HTTP response

Tags: ios, swift, xcode5

i am developing an iOS app in Swift using Xcode. How can I get values of Json object from this HTTP response.I need values of inner message and status.

```
{"message":"success","statusCode":200,"data":{"message":"already logged in","status":0}}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30480777/4519092)

Comment: Please check link. hope work for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30480777/1616632

Answer (score 1):

First, let me recommend the best 3rd party API for REST calls (HTTP) which called [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire).

If you use the below Alamofire example:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
     .responseJSON { response in
         print(response.request)  // original URL request
         print(response.response) // URL response
         print(response.data)     // server data
         print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

         // Parsing the JSON
         if let JSON = response.result.value {
             print("JSON: \(JSON)")

             // The actual cast to Dictionary
             let jsonDictionary = JSON as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
         }
     }
```

Basically `jsonDictionary` will be your JSON dictionary that the keys are `String` and the values are of type `AnyObject` (so you could cast to what ever you need) and now you can do the below calls:

```
let message = json["message"] as? String
```

Answer (score 0):

Get that dictionary and

```
let objDict = yourResponseObject.valueForKey("Data") as! NSDictionary

if objDict.valueforkey("message").isequaltoString("already logged in")

{

 User logged already

}

else

{

 not logged

}
```