# How to Convert Response String to NSMutableDictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Response String : 
`{"status":"failure","message":"link_inactive"}`

I would like the same format with `NsmutableDictionary` or `NSDictionary` so I can access via key value.

Comment: convert response string to NSData & then convert NSData to NSDictionary using NSJSonSerialization.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please make sure that you have read "how to ask a good question". Following these guidelines will make it easier for others to answer, and the responses you get will be better and show up quicker. Details are described here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Eric D said the original code:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33173192/846780

Try it:

```
func convertStringToDictionary(text: String) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
    if let data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers) as? [String:AnyObject]
            return json
        } catch {
            print("Something went wrong")
        }
    }
    return nil
}

let string =  "{\"status\":\"failure\",\"message\":\"link_inactive\"}"

let dict = convertStringToDictionary(string) //["status": "failure", "message": "link_inactive"]
```

Comment: Klevison i have try many code but i'm new in swift so i'm not exactly  solution.! you give me proper solution with well manner , Thanks

Comment: The least you could do when you "borrow" someone else's code is to give attribution. This method is copied from http://stackoverflow.com/a/33173192/2227743

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by JSONObjectWithData method of NSJSONSerialization.

```
 do {
    let jsonDict: NSDictionary? = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)) as? NSDictionary
    if let jsonDict = jsonDict {
    print(jsonDict["message"])  

  } catch let error as NSError {
    // error handling
    debugLog(error)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code it will help you

```
func convertStringToDictionary(text: String) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
    if let data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        do 
        {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers) as? [String:AnyObject]
            return json
        } 
        catch 
        {
            print("error")
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```