# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value while converting JSON Array

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swift2

while I try to convert Json String to Dictionary it gives me fatal eror: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

```
self.res = Jsn.convertStringToDictionary(self.sub)!
```

sub = [{"CityId":6,"CityName":"Ankara"},{"CityId":34,"CityName":"İstanbul"}]

And the function is:

```
func convertStringToDictionary(text: String) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
    if let data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        do {
            return try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as? [String:AnyObject]
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Can you help me with the problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show your actual response which is coming from server.

Comment: The function comes from http://stackoverflow.com/a/30480777/2227743 and is named `convertStringToDictionary`. Your JSON is an *array* of dictionaries...

Comment: Also, this function returns an Optional *for a reason*. If you force-unwrap the result on the caller side instead of handling the Optional, of course your app will crash.

Comment: @EricAya I am new with swift thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert it to `[[String:AnyObject]]` instead of `[String:AnyObject]` because it is **array of dictionaries.**

Try using

```
return try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as? [[String:AnyObject]]
```