# Convert JSON String to Swift Dictionary

Tags: swift

I'm trying to convert a json string to a dictionary.

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480672/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-a-dictionary) but it only works for arrays with one value.

Here is an example of a string I'm trying to turn into a swift dictionary

```
[
  {"value1":"Reporting for duty"},
  {"value2":"Post received"},
  {"value3":"frogg222"},
  {"value4":"Still reporting"}
]
```

Just to be clear, the following code does not work and will return nil with the above string.

```
func convertStringToDictionary(text: String) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
    if let data = text.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Your JSON's root is an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: @rmaddy and you've just solved the million dollar question. Thank you so much.

Comment: @rmaddy I caught that the very second I posted that comment. Thank you for the help rmaddy!

Comment: @rmaddy if you post your comment as an answer I'll mark it as accepted answer