# ios swift 3 get the Array in JSON file

Tags: ios, json, swift

How to read JSON file

```
{

"Title" : ["Introduction","Aggregation"],

"Introduction":{

    "content1":"LINQ is an acronym for Language Integrated Query, which is descriptive for where it’s used and what it does. The Language Integrated part means that LINQ is part of programming language syntax. In particular, both C# and VB are languages that ship with .NET and have LINQ capabilities.LINQ is used for querying data....",

    "content2":"LINQ is part of the Microsoft .NET Framework and is used to query data from specific data providers like LINQ to Objects, LINQ to Entities and LINQ to SQL....",

    "content3":"The LINQ to Objects provider contains a handy set of standard query operators to work with in-memory IEnumerable<T> collections."
},

"Aggregation":{

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

"subTitle" : ["Aggregate (simple)","Aggregate (seed)","Average","Count","LongCount","Max","Min","Sum"],

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    "Aggregate (simple)":{
        "Definition":"Performs a specified operation to each element in a collection, while carrying the result forward...",
        "Program":"",
        "Output":""
    },
    "Aggregate (seed)":{
        "Definition": "Performs a specified operation to each element in a collection, while carrying the result forward. Seed sets initial value. This Lambda Expression sample aggregates numbers in the array by addition, using a seed (seed is an initial value).",
        "Program":"",
        "Output":""
    },
    "Average":{
        "Definition":"Computes the average value for a numeric collections. This Lambda Expression sample calculates the average of values in array.",
        "Program":"...",
        "Output":"...."
    },
    "Count":{
        "Definition":"Returns the number of elements in a collection. This Lambda Expression sample counts names in array.",
        "Program":"",
        "Output":""
    },
    "LongCount":{
        "Definition":"Returns the number of elements in collections larger than Int32.MaxValue. This Lambda Expression sample counts elements in array larger than Int32.MaxValue.",
        "Program":"",
        "Output":""
    },
    "Max":{
        "Definition":"Finds the largest value in a collection. This Lambda Expression sample finds the highest number in array.",
        "Program":"",
        "Output":""
    },
    "Min":{
        "Definition":"Finds the smallest value in a collection. This Lambda Expression sample finds the lowest number in array.",
        "Program":"",
        "Output":""
    },
    "Sum":{
        "Definition":"Calculates the total for a numeric collections. This Lambda Expression sample sums three numbers in array.",
        "Program":"",
        "Output":""
    }

}
}
```

In above JSON File I get the Subtitle array

```
"subTitle" : ["Aggregate (simple)","Aggregate (seed)","Average","Count","LongCount","Max","Min","Sum"],
```

How to get the subTitle Array and the data is display from `UItableView` ..

I'm Read the `JSON` File 
How to save subTitle Array in Json file
And I'm also tried some other examples
but the example not understand for me

```
func readJson() {
        do {
            if let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "LinqContents", withExtension: "json") {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                if let object = json as? [String: Any] {
                    // json is a dictionary
                    print(object)
                } else if let object = json as? [Any] {
                    // json is an array
                    print(object)
                } else {
                    print("JSON is invalid")
                }
            } else {
                print("no file")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code looks familiar. ;) https://stackoverflow.com/a/40438849/2227743 Hint: add `dump(object)` where there's the `// json is a dictionary` comment and look at the structure. You can then access the key/value you need. This means go in "Aggregation" then go in "subTitle"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let data: Data // received from json file
do {
     if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
      if let aggregator = json["Aggregation"] as? [String: Any] {
         let subTitle = aggregator["subTitle"] as! [String]
         //send array to tableView 
      }
    }
} catch {
      print(error.localizedDescription)      
}
```

Comment: yes changes the code, my bad forget he is not using the third party library

Comment: the solution I have given doesn't use any library :)

Comment: whats the error coming? can you print it. If you have added the json file then make sure it should get copied in bundle resources. Go to build phases and check Copy Bundle Resources if the son file is listed or not