# how to convert JSON-String into Array of Dictionaries in iOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have this String

```
[{\"label\":\"Issue Name\",\"value\":\"my dirst iOS \",\"_id\":\"issueName\"},{\"label\":\"Issue DueDate\",\"value\":\"15-12-2016\",\"_id\":\"dueDate\"}]
```

I want to convert it to type `[NSDictionary]` for example;

```
[
  {
    "label": "Issue Name",
    "value": "my dirst iOS ",
    "_id": "issueName"
  },
  {
    "label": "Issue DueDate",
    "value": "15-12-2016",
    "_id": "dueDate"
  }
]
```

Can someone tell me how to do that. I Have Already Tried [How to convert a JSON string to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480672/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a JSON string to a dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480672/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: This does exactly describe how to parse JSON in Swift 1, 2 and 3

Comment: can you explain why the already answered question did not help? Did you get error messages?

Comment: server team should remove slash before each key and value and then by parsing with jsonserialization solve your issue

Comment: When i am using  suggested code. it is giving me nil @Volker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first try to remove the slashes

```
stringJson.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "")
```

then convert it with JsonConverter

```
func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> Any? {

     if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
         do {
             return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? Any
         } catch {
             print(error.localizedDescription)
         }
     }

     return nil

}
```

then

```
    if let list = self.convertToDictionary(text: stringJson) as? [AnyObject] {

       print(list);
    }
```

Comment: Right. But note hatim your highest level is a json ARRAY, so take that out first.

Comment: returning any in this case

Comment: Its showing error on returning "ANY" as "jsonResult produce "Any" not the expected contextual result type"[String: Any]""

Comment: Sorry my bad, i made a mistake in my code, I am not able to up vote the answer till u edit, please make an edit so that i can up vote

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 Easy way

```
//MARK:- Calling
if let list = self.convertToDictionary(text: stringJson) as? [AnyObject] {

   print(list);
}


//MARK:- Remove the Slashes
let text = stringJson.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")

//MARK:- Convert it with JsonConverter
func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> Any? {

 if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
     do {
         return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? Any
     } catch {
         print(error.localizedDescription)
     }
 }

 return nil
```

}