# Unable to cast notification.object to NSDictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, notifications

I'm working on payment gateway, in which i'm receiving response in notification type.
i want to fetch data from notification.object which is in Any data type.
I have tried https://nacho4d-nacho4d.blogspot.in/2016/05/dictionary-to-json-string-and-json.html this to convert from string to Dictionary, but my problem is i'm not able to convert it to Dictionary.

Also i have tried to convert it to String & then tried to convert it to dictionary by following:

```
if let tmp : [NSObject : AnyObject] = notification.object as? [NSObject : AnyObject] {
        print(tmp)
        //print(tmp[status] as? String)
    }
```

or

```
if let unfo :Dictionary<String,String> = notification.object as? Dictionary<String,String> {
        print(unfo)
    }
```

Comment: try `let tmp = notification.object as? [String : Any]`

Comment: This is casting to String that is right, but i want to convert it to Dictionary because object is actually Dictionary

Comment: `[String: Any]` is a Dictionary type. The same as `Dictionary<String, Any>`

Comment: I have tried both ways by [String : Any] & [AnyHashable:Any] but it is returning tmp as nil

Comment: What's the name of the class of your `notification` object ?

Comment: class is of type UIViewController
And i'm calling this function from payment gateway
func responseReceived(_ notification: Notification) {
}

Comment: what's the name of the payment gateway??

Comment: i'm using payuBiz

Comment: tried using https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Documentations/wiki/8.-iOS-SDK-integration point 7 for this.

Comment: Try this ....  `let aStr = String(format: "%@", notification.object)` ... and if this string is json and you want to convert string json to Dictionary ... See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30480777/1825618

Comment: From payment gateway doc they have given let strConvertedRespone: String = "\(String(describing: notification.object))" to convert it to string