# Convert a JSON string to Dictionary in Swift 3

Tags: swift3

as a coding exercise, I wrote a small program to take MySql data frm the web to the iPhone. On the server side. I wrote the php script to get the script to return the json data.

On xcode I have

```
[code]
.
.
.
     let jsonString = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:    [])
    print(jsonString!)
    .
    .
    .
[/code]
```

In xcode console, I have this:

```
[code]
(
        {
        Address = "1 Infinite Loop Cupertino, CA";
        Latitude = "37.331741";
        Longitude = "-122";
        Name = Apple;
    }
)
[/code]

I have a function
    [code]

func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
            if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
                do {
                    return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
[/code]
```

When I pass the jsonString to convertToDictionary(text:)

```
[code]
let dict = convertToDictionary(text: jsonString as! String)
[/code]
```

In the console I get an error "Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x10369bdb0) to 'NSString' (0x1004eac60)."

but if I hard code the json string then pass it to the convertToDictionary(text:)

```
[code] 
let hardCodedStr = "{\"Address\":\"1 Infinite Loop Cupertino, CA\",\"Latitude\":\"37.331741\",\"Longitude\":\"-122\",\"Name\":\"Apple\"}"

let dict = convertToDictionary(text: hardCodedStr)
print(dict!)
[/code]
```

It works just fine. Why is that? Thanks

Comment: This is not how you're supposed to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30480777/2227743). This function is only a convenience way of converting a JSON string to a dictionary *if you only have the string to work with*. But this is not your case: you have the JSON *data*. You should convert the *data* to a dictionary - forget the strings altogether.

Comment: The variable `jsonString` is already a dictionary converted from a JSON string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look closely at what `jsonObject(with:options:)` returns, you will see that it is a `[String: Any]` or a `[Any]`, depending on your JSON.

Therefore, `jsonString` here actually stores a `[String: Any]`, even thought the compiler thinks it is of type `Any`:

```
let jsonString = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:    [])
print(jsonString!)
```

If you try to pass this to `convertToDictionary`, which accepts a `String`, it of course will not work, because a dictionary and `String` are not compatible types.

How to solve this problem?

The problem is already solved! You don't need `convertToDictionary` at all. `jsonString` itself *is* the dictionary you wanted.

This is what you need to do:

```
let jsonString = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String: Any]
                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                                             Add this part
```

After that you can call dictionary methods on `jsonString`. I also suggest you to rename `jsonString` to something else.

Comment: Thank for the reply. jsonString is already a dictionary? That's how I got confused. I thought a dictionary has format like ["Address":"xyz", "Name":"Apple"...] (with square brackets.) This does look like it at all, that's why I thoght it is a Json string. So I can access it with the dictionary methods?

Comment: Yes you can. You just need to cast it to a `[String, Any]` first. @Tony

Comment: @Tony See the edit for how to do this! If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark!

Comment: It gives error " can not invoke jsonObject with an argument list of type (with:String,options:[Any])"

Comment: @Sweeper no, I am also using swift 3.0

Comment: I think it does not work if I pass String as a parameter

Comment: Oh are you passing a String? You should pass a `Data` as the first parameter @Mansuu....

Comment: There is some problem with my json format it contains string inside a json object and I only want to parse that particular string into Dictionary @Sweeper

Comment: @Mansuu.... Try to extract the string from the JSON first. I recommend you use SwiftyJSON to do this. Then you can convert the string into a dictionary by using one of SwiftyJSON's features.

Comment: I have installed SwiftyJson how to to using that @Sweeper

Comment: @Mansuu.... Check out the README and try out different things yourself. If you still don't understand, please ask another question since the problem that you're facing is out of the scope of this post.

Comment: How to get data that you pass to this method?