# How to parse data from server?

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting data like `{"OTP":"5480"}` in a string named responseString, How can I uset it.

My Code is.

```
@IBAction func signupButton() {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:"http://122.166.215.8:8090/RESTMVC/validateMobileNumber")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let mobileNumberString : String = self.mobileNumberTextfield.text!

    let postString = ["mobileNumber":mobileNumberString]

    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postString, options:.prettyPrinted)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }
        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        var recived = [UInt8]()
        recived.append(contentsOf: data)
        print(responseString!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "OTPView", sender: nil)
        });
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

and I want to change that string into Array. Or is there any way in which I can get Array directly on the place of String?

Comment: why do you need to convert this String into Array? This only has 1 OTP so an array wont be needed

Comment: An array of what?

Comment: how can I get OTP value from that string?

Comment: It seems like the response in the dictionary it is easier to use it by the key of dictionary like: `let otp = response["OTP"]`

Comment: @AdityaPandey You're probably looking for something like [this](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper)

Comment: you want to change the response in dictionary on array.
To convert in dictionary try using `JSONSerialization`
And for array try using `split` method of string.

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani  
it is throwing error. Type string has no subscript members

Comment: @AdityaPandey you have to parse your response to JSON..!!

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani how should I do that, I don't know. I am very new to swift.

Comment: You don't need to convert the Data to String. The data is already in JSON. This is explained in the intro text of my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30480777/2227743 (which was misunderstood and plagiarized by one of the commenters, then deleted): if you have the data, don't use the string, use the data.

Answer (score 1):

To access value of "OTP" you need to parse your response string and convert it in Json dictionary you can achive this using following code, just pass your response data in JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)

```
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! Dictionary<String, Any>

            if let otpValue = json["OTP"] {
                print("Otp value : \(otpValue)")
            }

        } catch {
            // Handle Exception
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get otp from dictionary like below.

`print(responseString["OTP"])`

Comment: it is throwing error. Type string has no subscript members

Comment: responseString must be a Dictionary type, convert your `responseString.result.value as! Dictionary` then access it.