# Parsing string json in swift 3

Tags: json, swift

I have a json saved in String format and I´m trying to use:

```
let json = "{'result':[{'name':'Bob','age':'27'}]}";
```

Using JSONSerialization comes error about Cannot invoke jsonOject with an argument...

```
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json) as? [String: Any],
   let array = json["result"] as? [[String: Any]] {
   for item in array {
       if let name = item["name"] as? String {
          if name == "Bob" {
             self.age = Int((item["age"] as? String)!)!
          }
       }
    }
}
```

I tryed to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480672/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-a-dictionary) solution but with no success.

Comment: If `json` is a `String` object, you need to convert it first into a `Data` object, because `jsonObject()` waits for a Data object, not a String one. Also, it's missing half the method, you are not writing "options" part.

Comment: @Larme The `options` parameter is optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the declaration of `jsonObject(with)` by <kbd>⌥-click</kbd> on the symbol.

The first parameter is of type `Data` so you have to convert `String` to `Data`.

A major issue is that the JSON is not formatted correctly. The string indicators **must** be double quotes.

```
let json = "{\"result\":[{\"name\":\"Bob\",\"age\":27}]}"
let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8)
do { 
   if let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!) as? [String: Any],
   ...
   self.age = item["age"] as! Int
```