# How to convert json string into a dictionary with swift 3?

Tags: json, swift

Im trying to covert this string into a dictionary

```
{
    "sender_id": 7,
    "Sender_name": Testchumthree Tester,
    "message": 42,
    "Sender_image": https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/281359099024687/picture?type=normal,
    "timestamp": "0",
    "group_id": 50
}
```

Below is what i found so far.

```
func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
    if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

But this i get an error saying the data  is not in the correct format. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is probably because of the nested double quotes. Anyway, as I explain in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30480777/2227743) this code is only a convenience method to convert a simple JSON string *if you don't have the original JSON data*. **Please instead convert the JSON data directly to an object (without converting it to a string before trying to convert it to an object).**

Comment: Please reformat your json

Comment: The error is right. All JSON keys and string values are required to be wrapped in double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your JSON is that strings are not properly formatted. There must be quotes around them and depending on the library "/" must also be escaped.

Try using this:

```
{
    "sender_id": 7,
    "Sender_name": "Testchumthree Tester",
    "message": 42,
    "Sender_image": "https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v2.10\/281359099024687\/picture?type=normal",
    "timestamp": "0",
    "group_id": 50
}
```

Comment: Good answer. One small note: apart from buggy implementations, `/` does not need to be escaped. *All Unicode characters may be placed within the quotation marks except for the characters that must be escaped: quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000 through U+001F).* - [JSON](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)