# How can I get the JSON response in dictionary format in swift3?

Tags: json, nsdictionary, json-serialization

I'm working on JSON serialization like below code:

```
  let jsonData: Data? = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: abc, options: .prettyPrinted)
  let parsedDict = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
  print(" parse Dict Value \(parsedDict!)")
```

abc data is:

```
{
  "ActedTime" = "2017-09-19 12:04:12",
  "EventDate" = "2017-10-06 07:03:29"
}
```

After completion of serialization, the response value is:

```
"{\n  \"ActedTime\" : \"2017-09-19 12:04:12\",\n  \"EventDate\" : \"2017-10-06 07:03:29\”}”
```

I printed the parsedDict like below:

```
{
  "ActedTime" : "2017-09-19 12:04:12",
  "EventDate" : "2017-10-06 07:03:29"
}
```

The stored data seems like string format, but data is printed like dictionary.

How can I get dictionary format for sent the parameters to another API like dictionary format.

Please help me,
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a JSON string to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480672/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-a-dictionary)

Comment: Already I tried but I had get [String : String] format. But I want only below format.
 {
  "ActedTime" : "2017-09-19 12:04:12",
  "EventDate" : "2017-10-06 07:03:29"
}

Comment: This is fine. Simply convert your date string to actual date with `DateFormatter`, setting format as `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: Sorry, my question is I stored the data in dictionary like below format:
"{\n  \"ActedTime\" : \"2017-09-19 12:04:12\",\n  \"EventDate\" : \"2017-10-06 07:03:29\”}”

but I don't want this type of format. I want only below format:

{
  "ActedTime" : "2017-09-19 12:04:12",
  "EventDate" : "2017-10-06 07:03:29"
} 

compare both responses. First one is seems to be like string, 2nd one is dictionary

Comment: If I print the data of "parsedData", it seems to be dictionary format.
I passing the same parsedData parameters to anther API, it seems to be String format. 
String format is not accepting my service, It accepts only dictionary format.

Comment: Both variants are strings, there is no difference. Your statement: `but data is printed like dictionary` - it isn't. What you have printed is json-formatted string, which (of course) resembles dictionary.

Comment: But how can I pass the parameters like dictionary format...

Answer (score 0):

Omit `.prettyPrinted`, the server doesn't care anyway.

```
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: abc)
```

And if the object is supposed to be a dictionary, why do you serialize it at all?

However if the data is supposed to be passed in a POST request as `httpBody` pass `jsonData` rather than `parsedDict`.

Comment: it's working but stored data seems to be like string format. My requirement is only dictionary format. How?

Comment: One of my API is not accepting string format, it accepting only JSON format.

Comment: JSON **is** String

Comment: String is converted to dictionary

let params = convertStringToDictionary(text: parsedDict!)

pass the value like 

        request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: []);


 Failed to load: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: The format depends on the values of the `content` and `accepts` headers.

Comment: how can get convert json string to dictionary format?

Comment: and my API parameters accepting only {} this format.
when I'm converting string to dictionary is seems like [].
But this not accepting in my scenario.

Comment: The data type to send via HTTP POST is **always** `String` (actually `String` as binary `Data`). The crucial point is what the string represents.