# Swifty Json parsing

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json, nsjsonserialization

I am using SwiftyJson library for parsing my following json

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "12345",
        "messages": {
            "message": "{\"data\":{\"msg\":\"HelloMsg\"}}"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use following code to get msg parameter

```
let json = JSON(data)
let msg = JSON(json["data"]["messages"]["message"])
msg["data"]["msg"].stringValue
```

However, I could not get the value of msg parameter. What shall I do to get HelloMsg?

Comment: What is the value of "message" (inside "messages"). Are you getting it? Only the "msg" is problematic?

Comment: Actually all the values inside message are problematic now I got the answer and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content of the `"message"` field is not parsed JSON, it's a JSON *string*.

Use SwiftyJSON's `JSON(parseJSON:)` initializer to accept a string as input and parse it as JSON:

```
let messages = json["data"]["messages"]["message"].stringValue
let innerJSON = JSON(parseJSON: messages)
let msg = innerJSON["data"]["msg"].stringValue // "HelloMsg"
```

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because `JSON(...)` is the wrong API to initialize and parse a SwiftyJSON object from a string.

You have to use this syntax:

```
let json = JSON(data)
let msg = JSON(parseJSON: json["data"]["messages"]["message"].stringValue)
msg["data"]["msg"].stringValue
```

From the documentation of `init(_ object: Any)`:

> note: this does not parse a `String` into JSON, instead use `init(parseJSON: String)`

---

Edit:

To test the code in a Playground

```
let str = """
{"data": {"id": "12345",
            "messages": {
            "message": "{\\"data\\":{\\"msg\\":\\"HelloMsg\\"}}"
        }
    }
}
"""

let data = Data(str.utf8)
let json = JSON(data)
let msg = JSON(parseJSON: json["data"]["messages"]["message"].stringValue)
msg["data"]["msg"].stringValue
```

The JSON as traditional literal string is

```
let str = "{\"data\": {\"id\": \"12345\",\"messages\": {\"message\": \"{\\\"data\\\":{\\\"msg\\\":\\\"HelloMsg\\\"}}\"}}}"
```

Comment: lol this time I decided to answer because I didn't see your answer, as I usually see yours first and so I usually don't need to do it... but now here it is! ahah :D

Comment: if I use   `let msg : String = "{\"data\":{\"msg\":\"HelloMsg\"}}"
  let jsonFromString = JSON(parseJSON:msg)
  debugPrint(jsonFromString["data"]["msg"].stringValue)` I am giving "" printed out

Comment: @ReinierMelian I have made the same solution as vadian, it works. I even tested in a Playground with OP's exact source text pasted in a file.

Comment: @Moritz yes but what I am doing wrong then?, I am trying to learn from

Comment: @ReinierMelian No idea. Here's a screenshot of my test: https://imgur.com/bALDRQY

Comment: its weird works for your file but to for String declared? @Moritz

Comment: @ReinierMelian I think you will get same result as we do if you double escape the quotes in your string literal

Comment: Same result @Moritz with `"\"{\"data\":{\"msg\":\"HelloMsg\"}}\""`

Comment: @ReinierMelian If you use Swift 4's literal string syntax it must be "{\\"data\\":{\\"msg\\":\\"HelloMsg\\"}}" because you have to escape the backslashes themselves.

Comment: "{\\"data\\":{\\"msg\\":\\"HelloMsg\\"}}"  show a compilation error for me @vadian

Comment: @ReinierMelian Maybe a misunderstanding. I mean the literal syntax let foo =  `""" ...text... """`. The syntax with double backslashes is supposed to work. I updated the answer with code to be pasted directly into a Playground.

Comment: forget about it, I can't make it work, but anyway thanks, if you can please post this example using a string variable to see how it works, I will upvote your answer @vadian

Comment: @ReinierMelian I added the traditional literal string syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The `messaage` is a string. not a JSON. so SwiftyJson could not parse it. You will have to first parse that string and than get the message from that using `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions)`.

You can refer to this answer to get the dictionary from that string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30480777/7820107

Answer (score 1):

Your second "message" key value is a String with a dictionary in JSON format, so you need to convert that string to `JSON` and access to ["data"]["msg"] then

**Code**

```
let json = JSON(data)
let msg = json["data"]["messages"]["message"]
let jsonFromString = JSON(data: msg.data(using: .utf8)!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments, error: nil)
debugPrint(jsonFromString["data"]["msg"])
```

**Output**

```
HelloMsg
```