# How to convert jsonString to json dictionary in swift 3?

Tags: json, swift

I am having an api in which after parsing json the response gets as below mentioned and after that I had removed slashes also but unable to save it into dictionary format can anyone help me how to implement this ?

Here is my code

```
func productListSortDownloadJsonWithURL() {
        let url = URL(string: sortIndicesURL)!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("Basic Z29tZXRvb2FkOm55UWREZ1ZYMWdYU1FkMmhHWEpN", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil { print(error!); return }
            do {
                if let jsonObj = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? String {
                    print(jsonObj)
                    self.secondIndices = jsonObj.replacingOccurrences(of:"\"", with: "")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)

            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

here is my json data

> "{\"1\":{\"attribute\":\"price_index\",\"sort\":\"desc\",\"sortLabel\":\"Highest
>           price\"},\"0\":{\"attribute\":\"price_index\",\"sort\":\"asc\",\"sortLabel\":\"Lowest
>           price\"},\"2\":{\"attribute\":\"rating_summary\",\"sort\":\"desc\",\"sortLabel\":\"Top
>           Rated\"}}"

Comment: Please refer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480672/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-a-dictionary

Comment: `jsonObj` is not a String, it is your desired dictionary. There is no need to do anything.

Comment: That already I tried but it didn't work @nikBhosale

Comment: by parsing it as string only it got parsed before it got crashed when I tried to get it as dictionary @rmaddy

Comment: then how to assign it to dictionary ? @rmaddy

Comment: Why do you *remove* the backslashes? They are virtually added to `print` double quotes in a literal string. Actually they don't exist.

Comment: then there is no need of removing backslashes then how to append it to dictionary  @vadian ?

Comment: If you really get a deserialized string you need to call `jsonObject(with` a second time to get a dictionary.

Comment: how to implement it ? @vadian

Comment: Just convert the string to `Data` and add a second `jsonObject(with` line

Comment: I tried as u said but it returns nil @vadian

Answer (score 0):

swift 3.0

```
extension Data
{
func dataToJSON() -> Any? {
    do {
        return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self, options: .mutableContainers)
    } catch let myJSONError {
        print(myJSONError)
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

Usage

```
if let dictResponse = data?.dataToJSON() as? NSDictionary {
 print(dictResponse)
}
```

Comment: it didn't work it shows error

Comment: It's pointless to use `.mutableContainers` in Swift. And do not use `NSDictionary` in Swift.

Comment: first remove with `jsonString.removingPercentEncoding`,  then try to convert in json

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

let yourDictionary = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data!) as? Dictionary

Comment: after parsing I need to pass the data into this ?

Comment: yes, you already have data, just pass it into this. It should work.

Comment: I tried to pass but I got error as shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjaT9.png

Comment: You are doing it wrong,

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil { print(error!); return }
            do {
                 let yourDictionary: Dictionary? = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as! [String : Any]
print(yourDictionary) 
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    }
                
            } catch {
                print(error)

            }
        }

Comment: then how to implement it ? @nikBhosale

Comment: Don't use 'jsonObj', use 'data' as argument directly.

Comment: it again crashed at the line what u said to change https://i.stack.imgur.com/QW0Oc.png

Comment: Comment everything and try only,

let yourDictionary = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data!) as? Dictionary <String, Any> 
print(yourDictionary)