# Convert Dictionary to JSON Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am new to the iOS development , I have dictionary as given below, I want to convert it to JSON, pass it to API

```
["checkinDate": "",
"data": [{
    "abc": 2,
    "cde": 13,
    "edt": 1,
    "shortName": "OCC"
}],
"incidentDescription": "",
"store": "ABD"
```

]

Code:

```
  let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: saveDict)
  let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
```

I have used below code but it is giving output as

```
"materialList": ["{\"abc\":2,\"cde\":13,\"edt\":1,\"shortName\":\"OCC\"}"],
"checkinDate": "",
"incidentDescription": "",
```

It is add \ while converting array of dictionary to JSON

Comment: I have also tried.      if let theJSONData = try?  JSONSerialization.data(
              withJSONObject: saveDict,
              options: .prettyPrinted
              ),
                let theJSONText = String(data: theJSONData,
                                       encoding: .utf8) {

                  print("JSON string = \n\(theJSONText)")


            }

Comment: *Convert Dictionary*. What dictionary? The *dictionary as given below* is neither valid JSON nor valid Swift dictionary. The added backslashes are normal (and virtual) to be able to display double quotes in a literal string

Comment: i think https://stackoverflow.com/a/30480777/4757272 should answer you question. Good luck

Comment: I’d recommend using the `codable protocoll` since it’s much easier to code & decode JSON data

Comment: The input data you have given doesn't match the output but apart from that the \" is expected behaviour as already stated so what is this question about?