# JSON Response data Ascending values in swift

Tags: swift, swift5

```
"buttons": [
 {
 "payload": "3",
 "title": "Check my money transfer status"
 },
 {
 "payload": "1",
 "title": "Need help with money transfer"
 },
 {
 "payload": "2",
 "title": "Have a question on Western Union locations"
 },
 {
 "payload": "4",
 "title": "General questions"
 }
 ]
```

I am getting the above response but the orders are different. I need to sort the order based on payload ascending order

I want the Final Output to look like this below:

```
"buttons": [
{
 "payload": "1",
 "title": "1. Need help with money transfer"
},
{
"payload": "2",
"title": "2. Have a question on Western Union locations"
},
{
"payload": "3",
"title": "3. Check my money transfer status"
},
{
"payload": "4",
"title": "4. General questions"
}
]
```

Comment: It's pretty easy to sort an array. What have you tried to solve this? Show us some code.

Comment: And how did you get/created that? Do you use custom structs? Some Codable struct?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert the json to dictionary. I hope you've done that. If not, refer this answer for doing that - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33173192/4637057

Once that is completed, you can follow this to get a sorted array. (I just gave the resulting dictionary, some name as "yourDictionary")

```
if var buttonArray = yourDictionary["buttons"] as? [Dictionary<String,String>] {
    buttonArray = buttonArray.sorted {
        ($0["payload"] ?? "") < ($1["payload"] ?? "")
    }
    print(buttonArray)
}
```

I suggest you learn about Swift higher order functions to learn more about these kind of techniques. This is a pretty good tutorial for that - https://www.appcoda.com/higher-order-functions-swift/

Check the "**Sorted**" section in that tutorial to get an idea about sorting in particular.

Answer (score -1):

Swift dictionary are never sorted. Quick Google search for Swift ordered dictionary will yield several implementation which may serve your needs:

For example:

https://github.com/lukaskubanek/OrderedDictionary

https://github.com/Marxon13/M13DataStructures/blob/master/Classes/OrderedDictionary.swift

Comment: This is about sorting an array and not a dictionary